# Filter Condition not applying to total

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, obiee, bi-publisher

I've created a report and want to filter the table down by a category. I've added the formula to filter the table and it works but doesn't apply to the total for that table. How do I resolve this?

The formula I'm using is below:

```
<?if:ROLE_='BRANCH'?><?end if?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the formula you provided is only surrounding fields in the table and you have done nothing to the total?

If you are using the sum function for your total, replace `FIELD` in the formula below by the name of the field you are summing.

```
<?sum(FIELD[ROLE_='BRANCH'])?>
```

If you are doing something else, or this doesn't work, please provide more information.